# MouseListener no movement

Tags: java, swing, mouseevent

I've been learning how to work with rpg style games in java and found a great tutorial. However, the tutorial shows how to move a sprite using a key listener, what I want to do is make the sprite move by getting a mouse location on the screen, and moving the sprite on its own without any key listeners. heres the code i have so far, thanks for the help! (oh, the problem is the sprite is not moving, forgot to say that... is it because of the while loop in the move method?)

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;

public class SpaceCraft {

    private String craft = "craft.png";

    private int dx;
    private int dy;
    private int x;
    private int y;
    private Image image;

    public SpaceCraft() {
        ImageIcon spaceCraft = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource(craft));
        image = spaceCraft.getImage();
        x = 40;
        y = 60;
    }

    public void move() {
        while ((x==Board.mouseX)==false) {
            if (x < Board.mouseX){
                x += 1;
            } else if (x > Board.mouseX){
                x -= 1;
            }
        }
        while ((y==Board.mouseY)==false) {
            if (y < Board.mouseY){
                y += 1;
            } else if (y > Board.mouseY){
                y -= 1;
            }
        }

    }

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public Image getImage() {
        return image;
    }



   /* public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

        int key = e.getKeyCode();

        if (key == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT){
            dx = -1;
        }
        if (key == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
            dx = 1;
        }

        if (key == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
            dy = -1;
        }

        if (key == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
            dy = 1;
        }

    }*/

   /* public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        int key = e.getKeyCode();

        if (key == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
            dx = 0;
        }

        if (key == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
            dx = 0;
        }

        if (key == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
            dy = 0;
        }

        if (key == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
            dy = 0;
        }
    }*/


}


import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.*;

import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;
public class Board extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

    public static int mouseX;
    public static int mouseY;
    private Timer timer;
    private SpaceCraft craft;

    public Board() {
        //addKeyListener(new TAdapter());
        setFocusable(true);
        setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        setDoubleBuffered(true);

        craft = new SpaceCraft();

        timer = new Timer(5, this);
        timer.start();
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);

        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
        g2d.drawImage(craft.getImage(), craft.getX(), craft.getY(), this);

        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().sync();
        g.dispose();
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        craft.move();
        repaint();
    }
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        mouseX = e.getXOnScreen();
        mouseY = e.getYOnScreen();
        craft.move();
        repaint();
    }

    /*private class TAdapter extends KeyAdapter {

        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
            craft.keyReleased(e);
        }

        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            craft.keyPressed(e);
        }
    }*/



}

import javax.swing.*;
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.net.*;

public class RType extends Applet {
    Board b = new Board();

    public void init() {
        b.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 400));
        add(b);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You must add a MouseListener to your Panel `Board`.

Change

```
public class Board extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
```

to

```
public class Board extends JPanel implements ActionListener,MouseListener  {
```

In the constructor add

```
addMouseListener(this);
```

Comment: ahh I see, let me try that!

Answer (score 1):

You need to move your sprite a little bit at a time, painting each step of the way. The way you're doing it now, you don't have any painting as your sprite moves, so it's just going to look like it teleports to the mouse location.

You also have to actually add a MouseListener, not just write the MouseListener methods.

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple approaches you can take.

First, you could log the current position when actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) is called on a mouse event, and keep track of the current X and Y.

Then you just need to make it so that during your game loop, which would have to be in paint() right now, you take the X and Y and apply it to the craft.

So add a call to craft.move(); in paint()

Then if you want to make it even better, instead of logging actionPerformed events, you can directly check the position of the mouse when you call craft.move() instead.

```
PointerInfo a = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo();
Point b = a.getLocation();
int x = (int) b.getX();
int y = (int) b.getY();
```

Is one method, although I think that gives you absolute co-ordinates, and you want them relative to your window, right?

```
Display.getCurrent().getCursorLocation();
```

or

```
MouseInfo.getPointerInfo();
```

Although that just moves the craft exactly to the mouse position. If you want it to have a maximum speed and travel towards the mouse position instead, you'll need to make your craft.move() method more intelligent.

Comment: When actionPerformed() is called on a mouse event? Huh? This answer doesn't really make any sense.

Comment: @KevinWorkman he's currently using an ActionListener to get the X and Y co-ordinates of the mouse when it is clicked, this invokes actionPerformed() with an event e which gives you those X and Y co-ordinates. He's already doing that, so I talked about that method, but there are better alternatives so I offered those. What do you not understand?

Comment: He's asking about a MouseListener, which does not have an actionPerformed() method. The approaches you described seem a lot less intuitive than just using a MouseListener.

Comment: @KevinWorkman MouseListener and ActionListener are both EventListener implementations. He does have an actionPerformed() method. That method is ultimately limited, however, regardless of if you use an ActionListener or MouseListener, so I recomended better methods which will be far more accurate for getting the position each time you render a frame.

Comment: I think you're confused about how MouseListeners, and listeners in general, work. EventListeners do not share a common method. You're proposing a polling-based approach, which is pretty strange compared to an event-based approach that most tutorials would suggest.

Comment: @KevinWorkman Event-based works better for mostly static GUIs, polling-based works better for active programs like games that are rendering every frame.

Comment: Again, I disagree with you- the OP wants to detect *clicks*, which are better off handled via events in this case. But this isn't really the place for an argument, so we'll let the OP figure out which approach makes more sense to him.